# How to run a command from /etc/sudoers.d/ file noninteractive way?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, sudo, non-root-user

I am automating dpkg-sig installation for one of my project purpose. Now I want to install it noninteractive way.

I have added the following in a file inside /etc/sudoers.d/

```
Cmnd_Alias DPKGSIG_INSTALL = /usr/bin/apt install -y dpkg-sig, \
                            /bin/apt install -y dpkg-sig
abc ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: DPKGSIG_INSTALL
Defaults:abc !requiretty
```

I am trying to install dpkg-sig using my golang code like this:

```
installDpkgSig := "/usr/bin/sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -y dpkg-sig"
executor.cmd = *exec.Command("bash", "-c", installDpkgSig)
```

It is not able to install it. Getting the following error:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: DEBIAN_FRONTEND
```

But when I remove *DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive* part from the installation command, it is working fine.
How can run the installation noninteractive way?

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to fix this problem. It doesn't require any changes on the /etc/sudoers.d/ file.

Modified the above code like the following and it worked.

```
installDpkgSig := "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && /usr/bin/sudo apt install -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -y dpkg-sig"
executor.cmd = *exec.Command("bash", "-c", installDpkgSig)
```

And as the bash session finishes *DEBIAN_FRONTEND* will be set to default.